# Cannot query "user": Must be "Model" instance

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm trying to filter users on my private user to user chat, I'm getting the `buyer`'s username with a model (`User`) **and** the `seller`'s username with another model (`Profile`).

The problem is that I don't understand how I can resolve this issue and why it occurs :

> ValueError: Cannot query "user_39": Must be "Profile" instance.

**On my view :**

```
uc = userComment.objects.all().first()
users = userComment.objects.filter(Q(buyer=uc.buyer) | Q(seller=uc.seller)) #error occurs with this line
```

**pdb.set_trace()**

```
(Pdb) uc.seller
<Profile: user_39>
(Pdb) uc.buyer
<User: user_4>
```

**Here are my two models.**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)

class userComment(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="buyer", null=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="seller", null=True)
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

On my models I don't want to change `userComment.seller` to `ForeignKey(User, ...)`

How can I resolve this issue ?

---

Full code as requested :

**views.py**

```
def addComment(request, gig_id):
    gig = Gig.objects.get(id=gig_id)
    uc = userComment.objects.all().first()
    users = userComment.objects.filter(Q(Q(buyer=uc.buyer) & Q(seller=uc.seller)) | Q(Q(buyer=uc.seller) & Q(seller=uc.buyer))).order_by('sent_at')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = userCommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(buyer=request.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('../' + str(gig.id))
    ...
```

**forms.py**

```
class userCommentForm(forms.Form):
    seller = CommaSeparatedUserField(label=_(u"seller"))
    comment = forms.CharField(label=_(u"comment"), widget=forms.Textarea())

    def save(self, buyer):
        sellers = self.cleaned_data['seller']
        comment = self.cleaned_data['comment']
        message_list = []

        for seller in sellers:
            sl = Profile.objects.get(user=seller) #Connection made here.
            msg = userComment(buyer=buyer, seller=sl, comment=comment,)
            ...
        ...
```

---

PDB Debug

```
(Pdb) uc = userComment.objects.all().first()
(Pdb) print('Seller class: %s' % uc.seller.__class__.__name__)
Seller class: Profile
(Pdb) users = userComment.objects.filter(buyer_id=uc.buyer_id)
(Pdb) print(users.count())
3
(Pdb) users = userComment.objects.filter(seller_id=uc.seller_id)
(Pdb) print(users.count())
4
(Pdb) users = userComment.objects.filter(Q(seller_id=uc.seller_id) | Q(buyer_id=uc.buyer_id))
(Pdb) print(users.count())
4
(Pdb) users = userComment.objects.filter(buyer=uc.buyer)
(Pdb) print(users.count())
3
(Pdb) users = userComment.objects.filter(seller=uc.seller)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your model `userComment` you have `seller` as `ForeignKey` to `Profile`, but sounds like you want it to be on `User`:

```
class userComment(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="buyer", null=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="seller", null=True)
```

**Edit:**

Sorry I answered it too quickly, your error basically said: you queried with the criteria `uc.buyer` on both `buyer` field and `seller` field, but `seller` is defined as a foreign key to `Profile`, so you can't use a user object to query on `Profile` field. Maybe you want this instead?

```
users = userComment.objects.filter(Q(buyer=uc.buyer) | Q(seller=uc.seller))
```

**ReEdit:**

You **should** use `User` as foreign key `seller` for `userComment` because that's what a relationship looks like and you could get all information you need use the relations. With `User` as foreign key, you could do everything:

```
# get a user's profile
profile = user.profile
# query with profile's information on `userComment`
userComment.objects.filter(buyer__profile__name='Tom')
```

Check django doc on [how to query across relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: Isn't there another way in order to use to not use `ForeignKey(User, ...)` ? Because I'm passing other datas through "Profile" model

Comment: I edited my answer, see if the explanation makes sense.

Comment: Yes the last one is the one I have now, sorry made a mistake in the post. But as I'm saying I'm I have to keep "Profile" as ForeignKey since I get some datas from there that isn't in "User"

Comment: Do you still have the problem or it's all fine now?

Comment: Please show your model code for us to understand your connection between `User` and `Profile`.

Comment: I added the full code as you can see the connection is made on forms.py

Answer (score 1):

Update:  Oh, that is very different code, it looks like your actual query is this:

```
userComment.objects.filter(Q(
    Q(buyer=uc.buyer) & Q(seller=uc.buyer)
) | Q(
    Q(buyer=uc.seller) & Q(seller=uc.buyer)
)).order_by('sent_at')
```

I would try:

```
userComment.objects.filter(Q(
    Q(buyer_id=uc.buyer_id) & Q(seller__user_id=uc.buyer_id)
) | Q(
    Q(buyer_id=uc.seller.user_id) & Q(seller__user_id=uc.buyer_id)
)).order_by('sent_at')
```

---

This is very odd, as your code seems fine from first glance.  I would recommend trying the following code to debug the issue:

```
uc = userComment.objects.all().first()
print 'Seller class: %s' % uc.seller.__class__.__name__
users = userComment.objects.filter(buyer_id=uc.buyer_id)
print users.count()
users = userComment.objects.filter(seller_id=uc.seller_id)
print users.count()
users = userComment.objects.filter(Q(seller_id=uc.seller_id) | Q(buyer_id=uc.buyer_id))
print users.count()
users = userComment.objects.filter(buyer=uc.buyer)
print users.count()
users = userComment.objects.filter(seller=uc.seller)
print users.count()
```

Comment: Thanks, see my update above.   But from the results of debugging, you can use my query using the seller_id & buyer_id to avoid the problem that you reported.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: It just worked when you printed out the count in your debugging statements above.  What’s the actual query giving you the error?

Comment: now it is saying that it should be a "Profile" instance.